# using CURL to accept file uploads php

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I am looking to write a function on one server to accept files uploaded from any other server in other words similar to a api.

Assuming on www.upload.com there is a upload script to upload a file. Instead of doing the post and saving on that server i would like them to curl my script on fileserver.com to save the files to.

My function on fileserver.com to save the file looks like this

```
 function upload($data) {

    $uploaddir = '/data/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . 'filename.jpg';

    if(move_uploaded_file($data['upload_file'], $uploadfile)) {
        return 'saved successfully';
    } else {
        return 'bad file';
    }

  }
```

and on the upload.com server i am testing the example with this:

```
if($_POST) {

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://fileserver.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'upload_file=@'.$data['img_file']['tmp_name']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is intended as a API so the functionality for doing the curl is strictly for testing. the upload function is the api function. Does anyone know how to do this or what I am doing wrong and is this even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I have coded something for that: https://github.com/chris-l/urImgAPI

My need was like this:
I had a site, hosted on a virtual machine, and there I had a form that allowed to upload  images, but I didn't wanted to waste the bandwidth of the virtual machine by serving images, so I got a cheap shared hosting service (which only had php) for the images  and developed a RESTful API on php that is installed there, that allowed me to save images from anywhere by using this API.

The API has a security feature to prevent that a random person could save things on my file server, by requiring a signature. The signature works like this:

```
$signature = md5(md5sum(your_image_file) . "your secret key");
```

And you must pass the signature as parameter on the request. That way, you never transmit the secret key and help to prevent that some other person could store images on your file server.

And while I created the API for uploading images, it can easily changed to host any kind of file. (maybe I will change it for that in the future)

Is released under the AGPL3 license, so check it and I hope it could be useful for you.